# How to edit php.ini values using PHP functions?

Tags: php

I currently using online server and i need to enable the `cURL` module (change  ;extension=php_curl.dll to  extension=php_curl.dll in php.ini file). But this file is not accessible and not editable for that online server. How to solve this problems using PHP functions?

Comment: PHP functions don't have further access than the userid the webserver is running with. Consult your hosting provider instead.

Comment: Hi. usually you can create you own php.ini and put it to the root of your site,but $mario is right call or text to your hoster to see what is avaliable

Answer (score 2):

You might want to have a look at `ini_set`.

PHP Doc link: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php

```
string ini_set ( string $varname , string $newvalue )
```

> Sets the value of the given configuration option. The configuration
>   option will keep this new value during the script's execution, and
>   will be restored at the script's ending.

Also, as they say in the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php):

> Not all the available options can be changed using ini_set(). There is a list of all available options in the [appendix](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php).

Comment: Of course, you'll need a different level of access to fix your cURL problem, but I do believe this addresses the title text of your question! :)

Comment: this won't enable him to add extensions to php!

Answer (score 2):

The author's real reason for wanting to ini_set() directives dynamically is to access a statically compiled library (curl) in a shared hosting environment. This is not possible in the case of a library which MUST be statically compiled into PHP. The answers are valid for the title of the question but not for the description as what he's attempting to achieve seems impossible given those constraints.

However, you can use the dl() function to dynamically load modules at runtime (if they are not static) https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dl.php.

However, curl needs to be statically compiled into PHP...

> To use PHP's cURL support you must also compile PHP --with-curl[=DIR]
> where DIR is the location of the directory containing the lib and
> include directories. In the include directory there should be a folder
> named curl which should contain the easy.h and curl.h files. There
> should be a file named libcurl.a located in the lib directory.
> Beginning with PHP 4.3.0 you can configure PHP to use cURL for URL
> streams --with-curlwrappers . This feature was moved to PECL as of PHP
> 5.5.0.

Perhaps if you just need to make a HTTP request, try file_get_contents (http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php), you rarely need curl in practice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the php's ini_set();

an example::

```
ini_set("memory_limit","1000M");
```

Check with your hosting provider to enable curl module.